# Sending GPS coordinated from Android to the Server

Tags: android, http, gps, coordinates

I want my background service to send current GPS coordinated to the server whenever location is changed. right now I have this code:

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            loc.getLatitude();

            loc.getLongitude();

            double lat = loc.getLatitude();
            double lon = loc.getLongitude();


            String curr_lat = Double.toString(lat);
            String curr_lon = Double.toString(lon);

            postData(curr_lat,curr_lon);

            String Text = "My current location is: " +

            "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +

            "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
```

The problem is that method postData is never called when location change. postData send current GPS coordinated to the server using HTTP

```
public void postData(String currLat, String currLon) { 
    // List with arameters and their values

    String Text2 = "String is: " +

    "Latitud = " + currLat +

    "Longitud = " + currLon;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.url.com/*.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myusername", currLat));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mypassword", currLon));
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        responseText = responseText.trim();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

What it is not calling function postData? Even it did not call it for once.

Comment: Is `postData` never called or is the whole `onLocationChanged` never called?

Comment: Also be aware that onLocationChanged can be called MANY times. If you set a debug point in onLocationChanged, you will see it can be called every second, maybe even multiple times in a second. You will probably want to set min time to update.

Answer (score 2):

You never register your locationListener with the locationManager. You should use one form of [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)

Don't forget to call [removeUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29) with your listener in the onStop of your service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you start requesting location updates.  Can you confirm you're calling the following:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip: rather than post the location every time it changes, only post it if the new location is better than the previous one. [Check this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#BestEstimate) for a way to determine if one location is better than another.